# New Microcontroller - programmer is not responding -

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I got an Arduino and after I was playing with it, I noticed that its internal micro controller si removable and decided to buy another micro controller. After I got the new one (atmega328P) and replaced with the original which came with the Arduino, I started to upload a sketch but it does not work.

I get the following:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

If I use the Original MC which came with the Arduino works fine, but with the new one it does not.

Did I buyed a bad/wrong MC, or I need to make something else?
Both have the same name :

```
ATMEGA328P-PU
```

The new micro controller has already a boot loader installed.

Comment: `The new micro controller has already a boot loader installed.` -- Are you *sure*? I have bought cheap chinese Nanos that haven't had a bootloader installed. If you don't buy it from a reputable source there is no telling what you may get. If in doubt program the bootloader on it yourself. Also make sure you set the right fuses on it.

Comment: @Majenko `Also make sure you set the right fuses on it` I do not understand this part. I plugged it the same how the original was. I also have two boards, and I followed Youtube tutorials about installing the boot loader and I installed the boot loader again and worked fine. But, after i decided to upload a sketch, got those errors

Comment: That's basic knowledge you should have before you start working with any microcontroller. The "fuses" tell the chip how to operate. What clock source to use, what boot vector, etc. All important stuff and has to be correct. You would normally do it before (or as part of) programming the bootloader.

Comment: @Majenko I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHF0UnpBXes) and I had no problems.

Comment: http://heliosoph.mit-links.info/arduinoisp-reading-writing-fuses-atmega328p/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by downloading [the latest version](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) of the Arduino IDE from their website and works fine now.

I use Linux mint 18 and installed Arduino via `apt` and I really do not know why I managed to install the boot loader, but failed with uploading the Sketches.

Comment: Likely you were trying to talk to the bootloader at the wrong baud rate, or were talking the wrong serial port.  If you only have the single board mentioned and no dedicated programmer or second arduino board to use as one, you haven't actually (re)loaded a bootloader.